# CSS for image inside visited link

Tags: css, pseudo-class, userstyles

I'm trying to use `a:visited img` in a [userstyle](https://userstyles.org/) for [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/), but it has no effect:

```
a:visited img {
    filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
}
```

On the other hand, if I instead use `a:visited` and `a img`, they work fine:

```
a:visited {
    color: red !important;
}

a img {
    filter: grayscale(100%) !important;
}
```

Why doesn't `a:visited img` work?

Comment: it's a security issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector browser don't allow a lot of styling with :visited

Comment: I think you can add a class after clicking the link. This way, all visited link will have a class. You can then style by class.